# How to find the biggest number of character containing word from a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array and I want to print the biggest number of characters containing words from the countries array. How can I do that please let me know.

I tried this way but I'm not getting the correct answer.

```js
const countries = [
  'Albania',
  'Bolivia',
  'Canada',
  'Denmark',
  'Ethiopia',
  'Finland',
  'Germany',
  'Hungary',
  'Ireland',
  'Japan',
  'Kenya'
]

let lnght = '';
let longest;
    
for(let i=0; i<countries.length; i++){
  if(countries[i].length > lnght) {
    let lnght = countries[i].length;
    longest = countries[i];
  }
}
    
console.log(longest);
```

Comment: What is the expected result? Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: you are initializing `lngth = ''` as a string, but then you are comparing it with a number `if (countries[i].length > lnght)` that won't work reliably. Furthermore, with `let lngth = countries[i].length;` you are creating an entirely new variable, which lives only within the loop's body, thus in the next iteration it's lost (and that's the reason why you always receive the last value in the array as result)

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by @derpirscher, use this instead, as it's `O(n)` rather than `O(n*log(n))`:

```
countries.reduce((a,c) => a.length >= c.length ? a : c, "");
```

### Old Answer

It can be done in one line:

```
let longest = countries.sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length)[0];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorting an array is not really an appropriate solution for finding a maximum/minimum, because it turns a task that can easily be solved in *O(n)*  (by just iterating) into a *O(n\*log(n))*  algorithm ...

Comment: @derpirscher Makes sense, but we must also consider readability also. If the array he's using isn't that big, trying to crank out a few milliseconds in speed in exchange for a little less readability doesn't seem worth it. However, I guess in this context, countries might be a huge array... idk.

Comment: `countries.reduce((a,c) => a.length >= c.length ? a : c, "")` is at least as readable as sort and is *O(n)*  And one-liners are not necessarily more readable than a simple `for` loop ...

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about `reduce`. I agree then.

Comment: Furhtermore, `sort` has sideeffects, because it works in place, and changes the existing array. It might not be relevant in this situation, but if one relies on a certain order in the array, using `sort` may produce some odd behaviour in other places of the code

Comment: @derpirscher true, I was considering adding `splice` to copy the array (which would only make it less performant). But your solution is simply better.

Comment: You probably mean `slice` ... but that makes everything even worse ... Because now additonally to the worse runtime of the algortihm you need twice the memory too ...